# Disable Standard button on change in picklist value

Tags: visualforce

I have a requirement in which there is custom object 'XYZ'. and on this object there is picklist field When i change value of pick list to 'Test', Realted List of Note & attachments "NEW NOTE" Button should be disabled.
Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 1):

The usability is obviously poor compared with disabling the button up front, but as the platform doesn't provide that facility, if you really need to enforce the constraint you can do it from a trigger that reports the invalid action to the user when they try to save the new note:

```
trigger MyNoteTrigger on Note (before insert) {
    Set<Id> xyzIds = new Set<Id>();
    for (Note n : Trigger.new) {
        if (n.ParentId.getSObjectType() == Xyz__c.SObjectType) {
            xyzIds.add(n.ParentId);
        }
    }
    if (xyzIds.size() > 0) {
        Set<Id> disabledXyzIds = new Map<Id, Xyz__c>([
                select Id
                from Xyz__c
                where Id in :xyzIds
                and Picklist__c = 'Test'
                ]).keySet();
        for (Note n : Trigger.new) {
            if (disabledXyzIds.contains(m.ParentId)) {
                n.addError('Notes cannot be added because...; click "Cancel"');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This trigger will fire for notes added to any object, hence some care is needed to do as little work as possible where the parent object is of some other type.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this unless you inject javascript into standard layout with Home Component, then add change event to picklist element. 
But safe to say, this is not a recommended solution, because salesforce doesn't allow javascript injection with home component and javascript injection will be forbidden at next release.